# Facebook is not picking og:site_name tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a page http://46.39.131.94:53157/FacebookShare/Go/f80b86a2-0b18-44c9-9de0-42ca465112f2 (don't mind the IP address, this is my home computer running IIS Express, when the app is finished I will publish it with proper DNS name). When I try to share this page on Facebook, the share post is created normally, but `og:site_name` tag doesn't seem to be displayed anywhere. Instead, my IP address is displayed.

I have tried the [Share debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2F46.39.131.94%3A53157%2FFacebookShare%2FGo%2Ff80b86a2-0b18-44c9-9de0-42ca465112f2), it show zero errors or warnings. In the *"Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties"* section the `og:site_name` tag is missing, but it is displayed when I click the *"Show All Raw Tags"*.

I have tried to "Scrape again" and refresh. Changed the URL several times. I am out of ideas.

I would expect the *"SHARE TEST"* (the content of `og:site_name`) to appear in grey caps just below the description instead of the IP address.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Having tried this on one of my [client's sites](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbroadbandcompareprices.com%2Fbroadband-in-my-area%2Frg7%25203ug) where the OG stuff appears to work in FB, Skype, etc. It appears that the IP address in your example is replaced by the domain name in their example. This is possibly something FB does as a security or transparency measure, maybe? That is, using the domain name or IP address instead of the `og:site_name` label.

Comment: I had those thoughts too. Only for some reason I was under the impression, that this is the place for the site name. Only I haven't seen a one single correct `site_name` value if it was different from the domain.

Comment: [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) states that the optional, although recommended, `og:site_name` tag should be used "If your object is part of a larger web site, the name which should be displayed for the overall site"... which is not terribly helpful. It gives an example of a name in text form, rather than a domain name, which suggests to me that FB is not using this value.

Answer (score 0):

I have written to Facebook support team and this is what they [said](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1153386624699119):

> That's correct, we don't currently show the "site_name" Open Graph parameter in the Share Dialog. We don't necessarily use all of the Open Graph tags on Facebook and in this instance we show the hostname or IP address from the shared URL.
>
> All the best,
>
> David

So, the `og:site_name` is not currently used by Facebook Share dialog.

That answers my question.